# Replace shortcode with a link

Tags: wordpress, shortcode

First sorry for the improper question format. Not sure how to write this.

My problem:

I've created a shortcode which fetches content from a post id and renders the post content in a text editor in the Divi theme (Elegant Themes - Divi). Now Divi releases a new Visual Builder which does not output the shortcode as it cannot parse this when the Visual Builder is enabled. But it shows when it's not enabled.

My Shortcode

```
function fetch_content_shortcode() {
global $post;
$id = "987453719"; // my post ID
ob_start();
$output = apply_filters('the_content', get_post_field('post_content', $id));
$output .= ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();
return $output;
}

add_shortcode('divi_content', 'fetch_content_shortcode');
```

Now I want to replace/convert the entire `[divi_content]` into a link which will take them to that custom post type post (post id 987453719). How I can achieve this.

Thanks and sorry for the bad explanation.

Comment: I can't see any usage of `get_the_permalink()`. Maybe this is what you need?

Comment: Not sure if it was a typo, but your shortcode [divi-content] doesn't match the shortcode function call of 'divi_content' (dash vs. underscore)

Comment: I have corrected the typo. Thanks but I am still finding a solution. The problem is Divi is not parsing the shortcode and they say this is the default behavior. So I want to make the entire shortcode turned into a link or simply hide this not showing any naked shortcode when the editor is not parsing this. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

`function fetch_content_shortcode(  ) {
    $link = get_the_permalink(get_the_ID());
    return '<a href="'.$link.'" target="_blank">Click</a>';
}
add_shortcode( 'divi_content', 'fetch_content_shortcode' );`

Comment: Thanks but the problem is the shortcode [divi_content] is not being parsed by the editor at all. So the link param does not apply here.It's showing the raw [divi_content] in the editor which I want to change or hide by all means. Hope I could this better.

Comment: Wrap content to filter apply_filters('the_content', $your_content);